# Project contained IIS Express

Tags: iis-express

I am looking for a way to make IIS Express contained within a project along with other tools project requires and being able to run project from that self-contained IIS Express. It looks like IIS Express stores settings under user specific %MyDocuments% folder, which doesn't help for my goal (CI eventually).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to rely on %mydocument% folder, you can provide your own applicationhost.config file(which contains all your settings) to iisexpress.exe with /config command line switch.
Following link may help you http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/